# How can i get xcode intellisense for created method?

Tags: ios, xcode, intellisense

Working in xcode I can see short description of method.
[image]

How can I get the same description for my methods/classes? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible right now in XCode natively.

You can use a documentation generator like AppleDoc:

[AppleDoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/)

Or wait for new versions of XCode, where it may be possible to do it.